# Will Zombie Pigmen spawn in a mooshroom biome?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been thinking about creating a gold farm and thought that for AFKing, a Mooshroom Biome might be the ideal place to build it since I won't have to compete with any other spawns.  Will they spawn in there?

I'm aware that normal hostile mobs don't spawn there, but I was wondering whether they work more like mob spawners in that the spawning is tied to the nether portal, not the biome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently in Minecraft Bedrock Edition, zombie pigmen DO spawn in the Mushroom Island biome.  I tried it first on a quick tutorial world to validate, and then built the whole thing and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer below for Java Edition

No hostile mobs spawn in mushroom island biomes, that's one of its unique properties. So no, your farm won't work there.

You should instead move it very high up, so that the ground is more than 128 blocks below your AFK spot. That way no hostile mobs exist down there (because they despawn that far away from you) and the efficiency of your portal farm is maximised. Except for Nether-based zombie pigman farms of course, they are much more efficient.

Comment: Farm works there in Bedrock edition.  Might want to double-check on Java.

Comment: Oh, this question is about BE, didn't see that. On JE there definitely shouldn't be any. I didn't check, but if it happens, it's a bug. And there are no such bugs reported.

Comment: One thing i noticed when researching this was that Zombie Pigmen are NOT considered "hostile" mobs.  It would be worth spinning up a large spawner in Java to test before calling this done.

Comment: From the wiki: "Technically no mobs other than mooshrooms spawn naturally in this biome, including the usual night-time hostile mobs. This also applies to caves, abandoned mine shafts, and other dark structures, meaning exploring underground is supposedly safe. However, mob spawners will still spawn mobs, and the player will also still be able to breed animals and spawn mobs using eggs." So not even squids or passive animals spawn. Indeed, now I remember that Xisuma once built a mooshroom spawner in a mushroom island biome using grass and he explained that no other passive mobs spawn there.

Answer (score 0):

Pigmen WILL spawn in a mushroom biome from portals, they are much more likely to spawn when lighting the portal (1-3 at a time from 23x23 portal im my test). Just tested 22/03/2020.

Answer (score -1):

Well, one thing I don't understand is why you don't build spawner in Nether then use entity cramming for killing. But an easy way to tell where to build is to check the biome, because I don't play Java I don't know how to show menu that shows biome, but if you build high enough, and I'm not 100% sure but it will spawn zombie pigmen.

Comment: I'm unsure about how you would build a spawner for this in the nether, but in Bedrock, entity cramming is not a thing.